# AzureAD user unable to login to Windows 10

Tags: azure-active-directory, intune

I have two machines joined to my Azure AD domain. I have a Surface Book and a Surface 4.

[image]

While both are joined to the same AzureAD domain, one accepts new users from that domain being added and the other does not. I am trying to add "jessica@nkdagility.com" to the machine so that she can login.

I have tried adding the user from the Windows login with "AzureAD\jessica@nkdagility.com" and with "jessica@nkdagility.com". And the message is always "workplace or school account cant be found".

[image]

Has anyone experienced this before? Any workarounds before I reset the computer?

**UPDATE**

So I was able to fix it but it required a factory reset of the Surface. Once done the user logged in no problem at all.

The Surface was on the latest Insider Build.

Comment: Try to add   azuread\    in front of your UPN to login your device. The user name looks like `azuread\martin@nkdagility.com`.

Comment: Do you mean that you cannot login with Azure AD account to this device after joining Azure AD, but you can use other local accounts to login this device?

Comment: No, this device was joined to the Azure AD domain a long time ago. I can login with martin@nkdagility.com, but my conigue cant login with jessica@nkdagility.com.

Comment: Hi, @MrHinsh , I did a test in my Lab, I can login other users with '.onmicrosoft.com' in my Azure AD after join the directory. Have you checked if jessica@nkdagility.com is in your Azure Active directory?

Comment: Could you tell me what is your Windows 10 version & OS Build ?

Comment: It was whatever the latest Insider build was on the Fast ring..

Comment: Hi, @MrHinsh.  Could you go to Azure portal and find the user , then create a screenshot for it?

Comment: No, since that would be a PPI issue... but they are a native Azure AD domain user with full licences. If you tell me which specicific meta data to look for I can provide that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160175/discussion-between-wayne-yang-msft-and-mrhinsh).

Comment: Usually, we can use other Azure AD accounts to login Win10 device which joined the Azure AD. According to your error massage, I assume that the account may be not in that directory.
Try to use Azure AD powershell to connect the AAD and get the user information **Get-AzureADUser -Filter "userPrincipalName eq 'jessica@nkdagility.com'"**

Answer (score 1):

Any user from the same directory should be able to login to the client that is Azure AD joined as long as the client has internet connection.

**Note:** If it's still failing then you need to perform intensive troubleshooting, I would suggest you to start from looking at event logs.

Comment: I agree that they should be able to login, however with nothing in the logs and no additional assistance I was forced to factory reset the device.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure exactly why this was an issue, but the only timely fix I could find was to factory reset the Surface Pro 4 to Windows 10. When it booted and I selected "device belongs to work or school" I was able to add the other user with no problems.

SO this may have been an insider build issue.

However, when I factory reset my Surface Pro 3 to Windows 10 it was still unable to recognise that user.